# How can I write each pandas grouping to a separate .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the code to group my data the way I want. See below:

```
names = pere.groupby('Investor Name')
for name, group in names:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to write each group to it's own `.csv`. I also just want to name each `.csv` a numeric value starting at zero and ending that number assignment with the last group name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use enumerate for count groups with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and `format`:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'Investor Name':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)

for i, (name, group) in enumerate(df.groupby('Investor Name')):
    group.to_csv('file{}.csv'.format(i))
    #if need add name of group to filename
    #group.to_csv('file{}{}.csv'.format(name, i))
```

Comment: This is perfect! How would I get the code to print the name of the group and the file name so I know which is which for mapping purposes?

Comment: @JoshPilson - You can create `dictionary` for `map`, e.g. by `d = dict(enumerate(df['Investor Name'].sort_values().unique()))`

Comment: @JoshPilson - Values are sorted, because also `groupby` sort by keys first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JoshPilson - Glad can help!